# Data Manipulation using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to copy a value in a dataframe uptil next NaN.

Here is the dataframe I have:

```
               Description
0              091SS16 GASOILA THREAD SEALANT
1              NaN
2              NaN
3              NaN
4              NaN
5              NaN
6              NaN
7              3M07447 SCOTCH BRITE PAD
8              NaN
9              NaN
10             NaN
11             NaN
12             NaN
13             NaN
14             NaN
15             600B 6" BUNA-N GASKET
```

And this is my expected output:

```
Description
0              091SS16 GASOILA THREAD SEALANT
1              091SS16 GASOILA THREAD SEALANT
2              091SS16 GASOILA THREAD SEALANT
3              091SS16 GASOILA THREAD SEALANT
4              091SS16 GASOILA THREAD SEALANT
5              091SS16 GASOILA THREAD SEALANT
6              091SS16 GASOILA THREAD SEALANT
7              3M07447 SCOTCH BRITE PAD
8              3M07447 SCOTCH BRITE PAD
9              3M07447 SCOTCH BRITE PAD
10             3M07447 SCOTCH BRITE PAD
11             3M07447 SCOTCH BRITE PAD
12             3M07447 SCOTCH BRITE PAD
13             3M07447 SCOTCH BRITE PAD
14             3M07447 SCOTCH BRITE PAD
15             600B 6" BUNA-N GASKET
```

Kindly help. Thank you!

Comment: `df.fillna` using `ffill` as the method

Comment: Damn, that's as easy as it gets. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `fillna` with `ffill`:

```
df.fillna(ffill)
```

Comment: df.ffill(inplace=True)

Answer (score 0):

`df.fillna(value = 'anyvalue')` will fill the nulls with a specified value

`df.fillna(method = 'ffill')`

`ffill` lets to forward fill value till the next not null value

There is also

`bfill` - lets you backfill value till the not null value before it

`nearest` - fills Nan with nearest non null value

`df.fillna(method = 'ffill', inplace = True)` inplace changes the value of your df inplace